# How to access $index value of ng-repeat within directive using ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am trying to access the $index value of the `ng-repeat` from within directive.
Here's my code:

```
.directive('myGrid', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'templates/my-grid.html',
  transclude: true
 }
})

// my-grid.html
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3] track by $index" ng-init="key = $index">
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>

// index.html
<my-grid>{{key}}</my-grid>
```

Because I need to use the key of the collection to design the template within index.html. This is a pseudo code where [1,2,3] is the collection. I want to use the the key with the collection to access custom value from the collection in index.html

Comment: I don't understand this what do you need to do with key? Is key basically just the size of [1, 2, 3]? which is 3 in this case. because if you assign index to key you will just rewrite the result until the loop is over thus key will equal 3.

Comment: No, key is the index. I am designing a grid for ionic. Here's the original code https://gist.github.com/nasifmdtanjim/90a4128bb1c54b920a80

Comment: what is the output? still not clear. Moreover where is your directive? In your code I see an angular state

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bZvVO

Comment: Here, I have only used 1,2,3 ... . I want to dynamically access the collection and change the values of the columns. Here you can see the key values. But it has been accessed from within my-grid.html. I want to access it from inside the my-grid directive. i.e. <my-grid>collection[key]...</my-grid>

Comment: Honestly I don't know what u are trying to do. Your question is not clear, but I think I can forward you to the right way. Use two way binding between your directive and your main JS/HTML. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

Comment: I know my question is not clear. It is difficult to explain. However, it is not that simple. You are telling me to use two way data binding between controller and view. But this is not the case here. When using ng-repeat it  changes the value at every iteration namely the key. I need to access this key in another template within a directive. So, it bowels down to accessing ng-repeat scoped key within another template where it was called as a directive. Honestly I don't know if I can make it anymore clear. :)